# Как задать элементам формы tabindex через JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Например, есть форма:

```
<form>
    <input />
    <input />
    ...
    <input />
</form>
```

Как присвоить каждому элементу input атрибут tabindex в порядке обхода дерева элементов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя JQuery:

```
var i = 1;
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', i++);
});
```